# Convert a function to be able to use it as an "on" event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have this function:

```
function isInView() {
  var windowStart = $(window).scrollTop();
  var windowEnd = windowStart + $(window).height();

  $('.box').each(function() {
    var box = $(this);
    var start = box.offset().top;
    var end = start + box.height();

    if (windowStart <= start && windowEnd >= end) {
      box.addClass('active');
    } else {
      box.removeClass('active');
    }
  });
}

$(document).scroll(isInView);
```

This function checks if an entire element is visible in the viewport ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7gr1qkeq/4/)) and adds/removes the `active` class from the element.

However, I want to be able to use this function as an "on" event, so that I can apply to many different elements. This would mean somehow converting the function and assigning it its own custom on event, like `isinview`.

In other words, I'd like to be able to use it like this:

```
$('.box').on('isinview', function () {
    if (elementIsInView) {
        // make the box red
    } else {
        // make the box the original color
    }
});
```

Or for a different element:

```
$('.nav').on('isinview', function () {
    if (elementIsInView) {
        // make the nav bigger
    } else {
        // make the nav the original height
    }
});
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Use `this` instead of `'.box'`?

Comment: So, from my understanding, you want to have your scroll event, figure out which element is in view, and then trigger a custom event on those elements?  If so I mean you pretty much have it, aside from triggering the custom event on the element.

Comment: *"How can I do this"* ... please be more specific. Take a few minutes to read through [ask]

Comment: @Taplar That's correct, I just don't know how I should modify the code to do what I want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rewrite it as a plugin, and trigger the events

```js
$.fn.isInView = function() {
  var self = this;
  $(window).on('scroll resize', function() {
    var windowStart = $(window).scrollTop();
    var windowEnd   = windowStart + $(window).height();

    self.each(function() {
      var box   = $(this);
      var start = box.offset().top;
      var end   = start + box.height();

      if (windowStart <= start && windowEnd >= end) {
        if (!box.data('inview')) box.trigger('isinview').data('inview', true);
      } else {
        if (box.data('inview') ) box.trigger('hasleftview').data('inview', false);
      }
    });
  }).trigger('scroll');
  return self;
}

$('.box')
  .on('isinview', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
}).on('hasleftview', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
}).isInView(); // call plugin after events are bound
```

```css
body {
  margin: 50px;
}
.container {
  width: 300px;
  background: lightgrey;
  padding: 50px;
}
.box {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: grey;
}
.box:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.box.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    var $window = $(window);

    function notifyElementsInView() {
        var windowStart = $window.scrollTop(),
            windowEnd = windowStart + $window.height();
  
  $('.bindInView').each(function() {
   var $element = $(this),
    start = $element.offset().top,
    end = start + $element.height();
   
   if (windowStart <= start && windowEnd >= end) {
    $element.trigger('viewEnter');
   } else {
    $element.trigger('viewExit');
   }
  });
    }
 
 $('.box')
  .on('viewEnter', function() {
   $(this).addClass('active');
  })
  .on('viewExit', function() {
   $(this).removeClass('active');
  });
 
 notifyElementsInView();
 $(document).on('scroll', notifyElementsInView);
 $window.on('resize', notifyElementsInView);
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 50px;
}

.container {
    width: 300px;
    background: lightgrey;
    padding: 50px;
}

.box {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background: grey;
}

.box:not(:last-of-type) {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.box.active {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box bindInView"></div>
    <div class="box bindInView"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The function shouldn't specifically name certain elements though. I don't want to have to keep adding elements to `$('.box, .nav').each(function() {`. :/

Comment: How else are you going to know what to target?  Otherwise you'd have to evaluate every element in the dom.  That's not a good idea.  You could always use a generic class, 'evaluateView', and select on that.  Then whatever elements you want considered, just stick that class on them

Comment: `How else are you going to know what to target?` you already know what's targetted - you've _attached_  the listener function to those elements already. When the function is invoked `this` will point to the current element it's being triggered against.

Comment: What event?  The only event that originates is the scroll event and that is on the document/window/body.  Not on the elements you want to do something to.  Scroll does not fire for those.  You may be binding a listener on the elements you want affected, but the scroll/resize handler has to know which other events to trigger the custom event on.